# Editing a plist in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I'm importing a plist into an NSDictionary object and want to change the contents of the plist once in the dictionary to lowercase. I have tried several different ways with no luck. Maybe I am supposed to edit the strings that are inside the NSDictionary, but then I don't know how to do that.

What I have currently imports the plist correctly, but the lowercaseString line effectively does nothing.

```
NSString *contents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Assets/test" ofType:@"plist"];

NSString *newContents = [contents lowercaseString];

NSDictionary *someDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:newContents];

for (NSString *someData in someDic) {
        NSLog(@"%@ relates to %@", someData, [someDic objectForKey:someData]);
    }
```

I NSLog'd the "content" string and it gave me a path value, so obviously changing that to a lowercaseString wouldn't do anything. I'm feeling like I have to access the strings within the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
NSString *newContents = [contents lowercaseString];
```

is change the path string returned from

```
NSString *contents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Assets/test" ofType:@"plist"];
```

so you will end up with something like ../assets/test.plist

you will need to walk through the contents of someDic an create a new dictionary based on the old turning strings into lowercase, if you are only concerned about values directly in someDic you can do something like

```
for( NSString * theKey in someDic )
{
    id     theObj = [someDic objectForKey:theKey];
    if( [theObj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
        theObj = [theObj lowercaseString];
    [theNewDict setObject:theObj forKey:theKey];
}
```

Comment: I presume you would use dictionaryWithDictionary to cope the attributes of the first dictionary, but how do I target the strings within to set them to lowercase?

Comment: No just create the new dictionary on the fly, there is you are going to just replace then new entries anyway.

Comment: Do I have to manually replace each entry? What if some entry were dictionary's with arrays and strings inside them? I'm just not sure how I would do this and can't find anything like it out there.

Comment: You will then have to do it recursively, create two functions or methods one that takes an NSArray and returns a lower case version and one that takes an NSDictionary and returns a lower case version, in these function when ever you find an array or dictionary call you array or dictionary functions with the diction or array and insert the result into your array or dictionary you are creating.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I will come back and up your answer when I can haha.